# How do I get the output of a cron script run from my home directory?

Tags: cron, stdout, stderr, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux and trying to run a cron job from my home directory (I don't have sudo permissions on the machine).  I'm setting a cron job by executing crontab -e and adding this line

```
30 18 * * * /home/myuser/run_my_script.sh
```

within it.  However, I'm observing that things don't seem to be running, so I wanted to figure out why. But running this

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ tail /var/log/cron
tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/cron’ for reading: Permission denied
```

doesn't help.  How can I figure out why things aren't running, or rahter where things are breaking down in my script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add to the end of your `cron` table entry:  `>> /home/myuser/myscript.log 2>&1`

This will capture the output to a log file.  By default, the output is mailed using the local mailer daemon to the user who owns the job, but I am not certain this daemon is running by default on an AWS instance.  If it is, try running `mail` as the user owning the job; you might have some messages waiting for you with the output for which you are looking.